# Need to disable Sympy output of 'False' (0, False) in logical operator 'not'

Tags: python, sympy, logical-operators

I am using Sympy to process randomly generated expressions which may contain the boolean operators 'and', 'or', and 'not'.

'and' and 'or' work well:

> a = 0
>
> b = 1
>
> a and b

0

> a or b

1

But 'not' introduces a 2nd term 'False' in addition to the desired value:

> a, not b

(0, False)

When processed by Sympy (where 'data' (below) provides realworld values to substitute for the variables a and b):

> algo_raw = 'a, not b'
>
> algo_sym = sympy.sympify(algo_raw)
>
> algo_sym.subs(data)

It chokes on 'False'.

I need to disable the 2nd term 'False' such that I get only the desired output '0'.

Answer (score 1):

`a, not b` doesn't do what you think it does. You are actually asking for, and correctly receiving, a tuple of two items containing:

1. `a`
2. `not b`

As the result shows, `a` is `0` and `not b` is `False`, `1` being truthy and the `not` of truthy being `False`.

The fact that `a` happens to be the same value as the result you want doesn't mean it's giving you the result you want as the first item of the tuple and you just need to throw away the second item! That would be equivalent to just writing `a`.

What you want to do, I assume, is write your condition as `a and not b`.

Comment: Thanks Kindall. This makes sense now. I see my mistake. I applied "a, not b" as it was the only way to get Sympy to accept 'not' in the context of a full expression which has other logical operators before and/or after.

I need to circle back to the original goal and learn if the inclusion of what you have suggested is appropriate. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the operators `&`, `|`, and `~` for and, or, and not, respectively, you will get a symbolic boolean expression. I also recommend using `sympy.true` and `sympy.false` instead of 1 and 0.